# C# Chess Board Printing the Rook in a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, chess

So on the chess board, the Rook has the option of moving up and down and left to right any spaces in that direction. I want to try and make a for loop that incriminates that. I wrote this and the Console printed out only the spaces near the piece, not any legal move. How can I reframe this so its shows all the moves it can move to?[image]

```
for(int up = 0; up < Size; up++)
{        
    theGrid[currentCell.RowNumber - 1, currentCell.ColumnNumber + 0].LegalNextMove = true;        
}    
for (int left = 0; left < Size; left++)
{
    theGrid[currentCell.RowNumber + 0, currentCell.ColumnNumber - 1].LegalNextMove = true;
}
for (int down = 0; down < Size; down++)
{
    theGrid[currentCell.RowNumber + 1, currentCell.ColumnNumber + 0].LegalNextMove = true;
}
for (int right = 0; right < Size; right++)
{
    theGrid[currentCell.RowNumber + 0, currentCell.ColumnNumber + 1].LegalNextMove = true;
}
```

Comment: What type is `theGrid`?

Comment: Note: "incriminate" relates to a crime...

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay it is an array set to a size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not using the loop variable, and so the body of the loop performs the exact same assignment each time.

Secondly, you could simplify this to one loop, containing two assignments: one for the horizontal direction, and one for the vertical one: making a cross. Then at the end, remove the possibility to stand still.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    theGrid[i, currentCell.ColumnNumber].LegalNextMove = true;
    theGrid[currentCell.RowNumber, i].LegalNextMove = true;
}
theGrid[currentCell.RowNumber, currentCell.ColumnNumber].LegalNextMove = false;
```

Comment: How could I change this so that I can use this loop for any piece for example a Queen? Would I just alter the currentcell and +1 or -1?

Comment: Queen has 4 directions, so then you need to perform 4 assignments in the loop. It is a bit more complex as diagonals do not have the same number of squares. If you cannot make it work, ask a new question about that. It will be again different for knight, king, bishop, ...etc

Comment: This approach won't scale to other pieces, well.  This takes advantage of the fact that the rook can only move up or down.  Imagine doing this for a knight.  As a simple approach, I would use OO to separate the movement by pieces.  So you could have a IChessPiece interface and implement a class for each type and its movement.  Then I would use recursion to have the piece crawl out in all the possible directions.

Comment: @Dan, this question was specific about the Rook. So when you say "separate movement by pieces", then this is exactly that separation for a Rook, and this code could go in a dedicated class for that piece. I am not convinced recursion is a good idea. It just takes extra stack space with no gain. A loop seems more straightforward. I would even use a loop for knight movements, although it would look quite different. One will also have to take into account that movements can be blocked by other pieces, or by the moving piece being pinned, or any of the other rules in chess.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your implementation looks like but I'm not sure how this will work.  In your example, your rook is at 3,3.  You're scanning from 0,3 to to 7,3 and then from 3,0 to 3,7, right?  As you said, there could be pieces in those paths so not everything along there would be a valid move.  So it seems like a better approach to simulate moving the pieces from its path outward til it runs into another piece or the edge.  Of course you can do this with iteration and it will work.  I think the code would be cleaner and easier to maintain as recursion.